# How to deploy react projects on Netlify from a git repository where there are multiple projects saved

Tags: reactjs, github, netlify

I have git [repo](https://github.com/TheKetan2/Master-React-v16.6.3-and-Redux-with-React-Router) where I have 4 projects codebase, now I want to deploy one of them on Netlify, Is there any way to do it?
I have signed up with Netlify and imported my repository there but there is no option of selecting individual projects saved in the main repo.

Also is there also a way to do the same with GitHub pages if yes then how?

Comment: In the build & deploy section, you can update the base directory, build command and publish directory.

Comment: thank you, was able to deploy it to Github pages. netlify is still throwing errors though...